# Wait until startScan finish the scan

Tags: android, wifimanager, indoor-positioning-system

I've a question about using the WiFiManger in my application.
The code is quite simple, I've created this service, that scans the network to get available WiFi:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mapName = intent.getExtras().getString("mapName");
    sendNotification();
    mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Check for wifi is disabled
    if (!mainWifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
        // If wifi disabled then enable it
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    mainWifi.startScan();
    List<ScanResult> scanResults=mainWifi.getScanResults();
    readAps=getAps(scanResults);
    //List of AP received in current position
    String result=compareRP();
    if(!result.isEmpty())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Localized in RP: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to localize you in this map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private ArrayList<AccessPoint> getAps(List<ScanResult> scanResults) {
    ArrayList<AccessPoint> temp = new ArrayList<AccessPoint>();
    for(ScanResult s:scanResults){
        temp.add(new AccessPoint(s.SSID,s.level,s.frequency));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

How can i add this condition: i want to wait for a "fresh" WiFi list, that comes when:

```
    mainwifi.startScan();
```

method returns.

Now my service still go on with the cluster matching algorithm, and i don't want it. What I've to do?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Fred

Comment: Register to the broadcast and you will have the list of wifi. You can't wait.

Comment: I've tried to resolve it with a BroadcastReceiver, but it doesn't work... for the cluster matching i need a complete list to do a comparison, so i've to wait until mainWifi.startScan() method return me "true". (Here the code example with BroadcastReceiver: http://pastebin.com/RxV2XFEi)

Comment: You should implement a Broadcast which will listen for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION. It's trigger by Android when the scan is ready. startScan is used to start the scan and return true/false to let you know if it started or not the search. You cannot wait until the scan complete. You should move your application logic inside onReceive of the Broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your activity.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        // This condition is not necessary if you listen to only one action
        if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scan results are available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Do what you want
        }
    }
};

private WifiManager mWifiManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    // You can add multiple actions... 
    registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver, intentFilter);
    // ...
    mWifiManager.startScan();

}
```